# How to catch Android soft keyboard next button event

Tags: android, cordova

I am using phonegap plugin for my app written for android. The design was completely done using html. I want to handle the next key event in android soft keyboard during text field navigation because i have used some plugins like niceditor(which provides formatting options in text area). So when i click on next button in soft keyboard from the field before to niceditor it is not moving focus to the niceditor instead app gets collapsed sometimes it closes as device does not recognize the niceditor as text field and so it is not focused on clicking next. so i want it to be handled manually.

Thanks in advance if anybody can help me out to get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
  editText = (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.editText);

            editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: i want to handle using jquery as i am using the HTML files for the design @msn